# file flush and sync with other program

Tags: windows, python-2.7, batch-file

I am running a Python script that is meant to launch a .bat file on Windows 7. The batch file runs a sort of Monte Carlo program for 2 minutes. At the end of those 2 minutes the program must update a data file that I will read later in the same Python script, do some data analysis on the output and relaunch the same .bat file if necessary.

I do this process an unlimited amount of time until I get a satisfactory output.

The Python code looks like this

```
import os
import numpy as np
os.system('myBatch.bat > messages.txt')

while True:
    # force flushing
    fd = open("output.txt",'a')  
    fd.flush()
    os.fsync(fd.fileno())
    fd.close()

    # read data
    data = np.loadtxt("output.txt")

    # some data analysis ...

    # testing
    if dataSatisfactory:
        break
    else:
        os.system('myBatch.bat > messages.txt')
```

As you can see I am trying to force flushing the **output.txt** file that must be written by the program in the batch file. As I have no control over this compiled executable program the output file is not getting updated after the command `os.system('myBatch.bat > messages.txt')`, but only after I kill the whole python process.

I tried to add the 4 lines after # force flushing, but apparently still not working.

For the sake of clarification, the input of the executable is the **output.txt** as well as the output, so the executable must over-write the file **output.txt**.

The file **messages.txt** is to redirect all the messages of the executable from the stdout to **messages.txt**.

Any advice or a hint?

NB: The batch file looks like this

```
.\TheExecutable %output.txt
```

Comment: `TheExecutable %output.txt`: why do you have a percent symbol there?

Answer (score 0):

1. if your batch file does nothing but calling your monte carlo program, get rid of it and call the program directly from python: `os.system("TheExecutable.exe output.txt")`
2. If you can make your program write to standard output instead of a file, you could use `subprocess.check_output("TheExecutable.exe")` which just returns that standard output. See [the documentation of numpy.loadtxt()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html#numpy.loadtxt) for functions loading from string instead of a filename.
   This way, you completely avoid writing & reading to/from disk.